# What is the difference between "all butter" vs "butter"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Japan had a lower consumption of **butter** compared with Russia.
Japan had a lower consumption of **all butter** compared with Russia.

1. Do the two sentences above mean the same? please explain

Japan had a lower consumption of **salted butter** compared with Russia.
Japan had a lower consumption of **butter** compared with Russia.

2. Do the word **salted butter** can be replaced into **butter**? please explain

I would really appreciate for every comment! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You do realise that some butter is salted, and some isn't? The word "butter" on its own might mean "salted butter", "unsalted butter", or "all butter" in any given context. Come to that, it might mean "yak butter" or similar, rather than butter made from cows' milk.

Comment: I have a conflict with my colleagues about writing a conclusion.
They said: This sentence "Japan had a lower consumption of butter compared with Russia." means "Japan had a lower consumption of all butter compared with Russia." and your data only shows Japan had a lower consumption of salted butter,clarified butter, and european butter

Comment: “Japan consumes less butter than Russia.” The butters are in truth whatever the respective countries count. Also it’s not clear whether this is the whole country or per capita, which makes a big difference if you’re drawing health implications.

Comment: I'd say (b) 'Japan had a lower consumption of all butter compared with Russia' needs rephrasing. Is 'Looking at total butter consumption [ie including all types], per capita consumption was higher in Russia than in Japan' what is meant? (a) could do with tightening up also.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to be really, really pedantic, one can argue that the sentence

> Japan had a lower consumption of all butter, compared with Russia.

is ambiguous. It can be taken to mean

> **(1)** Japan had a lower consumption of all butter **in aggregate**, compared with Russia (i.e. the total quantity of all kinds of butter, taken together, that was consumed in Japan was lower than the total quantity of all kinds of butter, taken together, that was consumed in Russia).

However, the sentence could also be interpreted as:

> **(2)** Japan had a lower consumption of all kinds of butter, **considered separately**, compared with Russia (i.e. less X-type butter was consumed in Japan than in Russia, less Y-type butter was consumed in Japan than in Russia, less Z-type butter was consumed in Japan than in Russia, etc. for all kinds of butter).

The other sentence

> Japan had a lower consumption of butter than Russia.

is unambiguous: it can only be interpreted as (1).

If one is not really, really pedantic, the possibility of interpreting the first sentence as (2) won't occur to one, unless there is something in the context that calls for interpreting it that way. One will thus assume that that sentence means (1) and will treat the two sentences that the question is about as interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of adding qualifiers:

*Two shops were in competition in a street. The owner of shop A put up a sign “CHEAPEST IN THE STREET!” Shop B then put up a sign “CHEAPEST IN THE TOWN!” So A changed his sign to “CHEAPEST IN THE COUNTRY!” And B’s response was “CHEAPEST IN THE WORLD!” A replied with “CHEAPEST IN THE UNIVERSE!” B thought for a while, and put up a sign “CHEAPEST!”*

Adjectival modifiers restrict or are emphatic. In your example “butter” is an uncountable noun and its meaning encompasses all those things which have the quality of “butter” regardless of any other attribute (including “salted”)– **all** is basically an emphatic and unnecessary – omit it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111904/discussion-on-answer-by-greybeard-what-is-the-difference-between-all-butter-vs).